# Html Javascript Animation

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I am trying to have an image slide from the left side screen and stop at the end of the right side of the screen. This is my code in index.html and index.js. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

HTML

```js
function getOff(){
  z = this.ElementId;
  x = document.getElementById('bruno' + z);
  return x.offsetLeft;
}

function move_right(value){
  var y = getOff();
  x.style.left = y + value;
}
```

```html
<div class="divBall">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <img class="bruno" src="bruno-fernandes-slide.png" alt="bruno fernandes slide" 
  height="250" width="200" padding="0" id="1" onmouseover="getOff(); move_right(200);" >
</div>
```

Comment: What you're trying to do? What do you see that does not work? If you provide these things, it would be easier for us to answer.

Comment: use https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @tobyharnish I am trying to click a botton and then when i click the button i want it to move the image to the right. I think my coding is just completely off

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this.

Javascript

```
var imgObj = null;
function init(){
imgObj = document.getElementById('bruno');
imgObj.style.position= 'relative';
imgObj.style.left = '0px';
}    
function moveRight(){
imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 10 + 'px';

}
window.onload =init;
```

html

```
 <div id="box">
    <p><button onclick="moveRight();">Click Me To Slide</button></p>
    <div id="bruno"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="webLogos"></div>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
```

css

```
#box {
background: white;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 300px;
width: 600px;
}

div#bruno {
content:url(bruno-fernandes-slide.png);
width: 200px;
height: 250px;
}​
```